# My LAMP Server Spits out ï»¿ before anything

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have a lamp server and it has an output that I think is also the cause of preventing page redirections using `header('location: xxxx');`

it doesn't always show up but sometimes it just outputs `ï»¿`

I am using `ob_start('ob_gzhandler');` , the only thing that I thought might be causing this, can anyone help please?

**UPDATE**
I used Dreamweaver sometimes and I think it's the editor that's causing it.  It only shows Unicode options when I try to save:

- C (Canonical Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition)
- KC (Compatibility Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition)
- KD (Compatibility Decomposition)
- D (Canonical Decomposition)

and then a check mark for "Include Unicode Signature (BOM) 
which I never check off  even though my problem is the BOM

Comment: Probably the UTF-8 BOM (byte order mark) showing up for some reason, ie if you interpret the data in some other character set.

Comment: yes thats what it is, but how do I do UTF-8 without BOM?

Comment: No it pretty random to my knowledge.

Comment: This used to happen to my files whenever I changed the encoding from ANSI to UTF-8 in Notepad++. Komodo did not cause this though. Now Notepad++ has `Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`

Comment: Majid Joon I use Dreamweaver baba. And I will look to see how I can save it as UTF-* it doesn't have the option on the Save as window.

Comment: @Neo - In Notepad++ this option is not in `Save as` either. It has a menu specifically called `Encoding`. I'm not a Dreamweaver user, but it is hard to imagine it misses such basic functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try correcting this by changing your content type.

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: this seems to force the browser to ignore even the files are saved with BOM.

Answer (score 4):

ï»¿ is BOM for UTF-8, so try saving the file with "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding and check if it solves it.

Comment: +1 Your answer was very helpful, byt Mike Vysocka's answer fixed the problem.